# Unit test for INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS on Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

in my app I have a method that checks whether INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS is set and if so, then performs a certain action.

In order to properly unit test this, I need to test both cases:

Case1: INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS == 0

Case2: INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS == 1

Is there any way I can set the value of INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS in my unit test? When I try to modify it, I get the following exception, which is understandable...

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to secure settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS

Comment: If you are testing with a test project, maybe you could add this permission to that, and not your actual application. Just thinking out loud...

Comment: @StevenByle I tried adding that permission (WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS) to the test package's manifest, but now I get the following error: "permission is only granted to system apps"

Comment: So this is an actual setting the user sets... You could setup an emulator with it on, and another with it off. I know that isn't a true solution, as it would be desired to run in one suite. However, this is a device configuration test, and I cannot see another way to automate this other than test each config separately.